# Generate a report in Yii framework

Tags: yii

I'm new for the yii and I developed a student management system using yii. Now I want to Generate a report to view Student Details.But I have no idea. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You are using yii1 or yii2 ?

Comment: I'm using yii1 framework

Comment: What do you have so far? Could you post some code? 
If you have for example table called Student, yii can autogenerate some code for you with [gii](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/07/creating-models-views-and-controllers-in-yii-2/), so that you can just edit it.